# Unity URP foam shader bug?

Tags: unity-game-engine, shader-graph, urp

When I'm in a scene view I can see the sea foam

[image]

But when I'm in game I do not see the foam. **Why is this?**

[image]

Basic Sea Foam Shader Graph
[image]

DepthFade subgraph
[image]